# EventBridge LimitExceededException: The requested resource exceeds the maximum number allowed for AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-aws-modules

While trying to create a new EventBridge rule, we are getting:

> LimitExceededException: The requested resource exceeds the maximum number allowed for AWS

exception, even though we have only `73` existing event bridge rules in `one region` and as per [Amazon EventBridge quotas](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-quota.html#eb-limits) documentation the maximum number of rules that can be defined in a given region is 300.

Please provide some pointers if we are missing something here.

Snippet of code for creating EventBridge rule:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "testing" {
  count       = var.some_condition ? 1 : 0
  name        = var.resource_name
  event_pattern = jsonencode({
    "detail" = {
      "requestParameters" = {
        "key"        = [for val in var.my_list : { wildcard = "${val["v1"]}/*/" }]
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Where my_list is :

```
my_list = [
  {
    "v1" = "myV1"
  }
]
```

Complete error:

```
│ Error: creating EventBridge Rule (test-eb): LimitExceededException: The requested resource exceeds the maximum number allowed.
│ 
│   with module.sample.aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.testing[0],
│   on modules/test/main.tf line 30, in resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "testing":
│   30: resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "testing" {
```

Comment: Well, that code snippet shows you would create only one or no rules, so it's not really helpful.

Comment: @MarkoE, sorry i couldnt  understand your query, but to make it more clear I have updated my question. Please let me know regarding what you need more info.

Comment: As mentioned in my previous comment, the `count` meta-argument shows your creating either one or zero instances of the resource. I don't see where 73 is coming from.

Comment: By 73, i meant the existing number of EB rules is 73 in total. As per docs we can definitely add more in the current region. Hence getting `LimitExceededException` had me suspect if the TF script has something to do with it.

Comment: Can you share the entire error message as you see it when running plan/apply?

Comment: Is it possible you have created and eliminated these rules quickly and have reached 300 in a short amount of time? If that's the case, give it some time and you will be able to create new rules. I had a similar issue with lightsail instances quota.

Comment: Hi @Riz, can you suggest how long we should wait, since i tried re-applying after 15 mins of gap, but it didnt fix anything.

Comment: @MarkoE i have updated my question with the exact error

Comment: I tried after ~8 hours (because I was away from my pc). So I can't be sure about the time.

Comment: I would recommend just doing an AWS CLI command to view the rules you have. If AWS things you have 300, then maybe this will show what it is counting